# how to register a model item as a view in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model named Product

```
class Product(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=False, default=timezone.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=False, null=True, default="")
    item_in_stock = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=True, default=0)
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=True, default=0.0)
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and in my django admin panel i want to add a model item from my product model into the side panel [like here in ADMININFO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hvHi.png) but instead of `All Products` i want to have a product item. for example if i have a product named `Shoes` i want it to show on the side bar under ADMININFO and when you click it it shows you it's values?

Thanks in advance.❤️

Comment: I'd suggest you read django's documentation first and try to do it yourself. If there's a problem, then you can ask it here.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 0):

###### You can use `ListView` class-based View :

in `views.py` of your app directory

```py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Product

class ProductView(ListView):
    template_name = "index.html"
    model = Product                 # Just point the model not instantiate it
```

*Django expose all data in model to html template automatically with the name `object_list`* 
*you can change the name "object_list" with: `context_object_name`*

```py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Product

class ProductView(ListView):
    template_name = "index.html"
    model = Product                 

    context_object_name = "products"
```

*if you want specific query to the database use `get_queryset()`*

```py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Product

class ProductView(ListView):
    template_name = "index.html"
    model = Product                 

    context_object_name = "products"

    def get_queryset(self):    
    base_query = super().get_queryset()
    data = base_query.filter(rating_gt=4)
    return data
```